# Akka, how can i preserve the sender reference when working with simple Java object and Futures?

Tags: java, spring, akka

I have a Java class which creates a supervisor Actor which then creates a child actor for each request it needs to generate.

1. Java class uses a Future to get response back from supervisor Actor
2. Supervisor uses tell and sender reference to get response back from child Actor

However my supervisor Actor is a singleton scoped bean so i need to be able find a way to store the sender reference each time my Java class makes a request to the supervisor. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think singleton scope is a good isea, as Akka needs to be able to restart actors when exceptions occur. That might lead to some weird problems. We used prototype scope ourselves.

Other than that, one possibility is to simply decouple receiving the request and sending the response by passing the server through your actors, you just use forward instead of tell, and the last actor in your pipeline will respond to the sender. This way the supervisor does not need to care about the response. Obviously this is ideal if your supervisor does nothing but sending the response to the sender.

If there is some processing to be done before sending the response, you can create a temporary actor and pass it the sender reference, and let this actor collect the results, send the response to your future and stop itself. This is especially useful if you need to wait for more than one response and aggregate it.

You can also add the sender reference to the message you send from the supervisor to your actors and back to the supervisor. Simple, yet effective.

Comment: yes using forward is a good way to manage returning the response to the correct sender however the ability to throttle requests is key. How do you recommend i do this if i cannot mark actor as singleton?

Comment: what has throttling to do with singleton? like i said, if you only create one actor, you will only have one actor, regardless if it has singleton or prototype scope. if you create multiple actors, but want only one and solve this by using singleton, then this is a problem. all that aside, throttling is indeed not easy to do. there is a pattern in the docs for that: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/scala/howto.html#throttling-messages

Comment: I should have been more detailed..I'm using Akka's TimerBasedThrottler class to implement throttling in my application. This class allows you to specify a throttling rate when creating an Actor. The new ActorRef can then specify a child Actor which messages can be forwarded onto. Messages will not be dealt with any faster than the throttling rate specified during creation of the first actor...this is why i wanted to ensure i only have a single instance of the Actor which defines the throttling rate